What kind of polymeric anions can be made of boron and sulfur?
Boron sulfide is polymeric. What happens to that structure if another sulfide (or multiple sulfides) is added? Is it always going to make a compound with small thioborate (not sure if this is the correct word) molecular ions or can it maintain the polymeric nature in some cases. I need examples.

https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.76.70 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022309385900262 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0025540883900806

Well, looks like you can make interesting glasses this way.

Boron and sulfur can form quite complex polymeric ion structures. One such structure is the $\ce{[B_{10}S_{18}^{6-}]_x}$ polymer[1], as the salt $\ce{Li6B_{10}S_{18}}$.   The open structure of this polymer allows the incorporation of additional lithium, sulfide and halide ions to provide ionic conductivity as a solid electrolyte.
The $\ce{[B_{10}S_{18}^{6-}]_x}$ structure is based on a supertetrahedral $\ce{B_{10}S_{20}}$ monomer. The numbers 10 and 20 are respectively the third and fourth tetrahedral numbers, and we can think of the sulfur atoms as being arranged in the fourth tetrahedral number array whose interstices, corresponding to the third tetrahedral number array, fit the ten boron atoms. The stoichiometry $\ce{B_{10}S_{18}}$ in the polymeric structure comes from the four outermost sulfur atoms serving as bridges between two tetrahedral clusters so that only half of these effectively belong to each individual cluster, similar to counting bridging oxygen atoms in silica and silicate minerals.
The charge formally corresponds to a collection of $\ce{B^{3+}}$ and $\ce{S^{2-}}$ ions. Even though there is little electronegativity difference between these two elements, the coordination numbers in the cluster structure are too high to be accommodated by covalent bonding alone; thus the ionic character of the bonding must be enhanced.
Reference

Kaup K, Assoud A, Liu J, Nazar LF. "Fast Li-Ion Conductivity in Superadamantanoid Lithium Thioborate Halides." Angew Chem Int Ed Engl. 2021 Mar 22; 60(13):6975-6980. doi: 10.1002/anie.202013339. Epub 2021 Feb 17. PMID: 33245819.

